# Why it crashs and tell me "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" while I click any NSMenuItem on my App?

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, gn

I build an app using GN and Run it on Xcode. but when I click any item on the menu, it always crash at main.m

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
    // Setup code that might create autoreleased objects goes here.
  }
  return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv); //crash at this line. exc_bad_access
}
```

and I can only get something like this

```
0x7ff8117a61e3 <+795>:  nop    
    0x7ff8117a61e4 <+796>:  nopl   (%rax)
    0x7ff8117a61e8 <+800>:  movq   (%r15), %rdi
    0x7ff8117a61eb <+803>:  movq   0x3ee419f6(%rip), %rsi    ; "run"
    0x7ff8117a61f2 <+810>:  callq  *0x3d44d040(%rip)         ; (void *)0x00007ff80eb85040: objc_msgSend
->  0x7ff8117a61f8 <+816>:  movl   $0x7, %edi. //Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

Comment: Do you have breakpoints set on Swift errors and Objective-C exceptions?  That often gives better information about crashes.

Comment: @PhillipMills there is little info about stack. It directly crash and left me above infos. Today I found another clue. When I double-click my app, not using Xcode to run. It behaves normally and menu displays well. However this doesn't work if use Xcode to run.

Comment: Unknown submenu: "Xcode.IDEPegasusSourceEditor.MenuDefinition.SourceCodeAuxiliaryEditorMenuItem3" in menu: "Xcode.IDEPegasusSourceEditor.MenuDefinition.Editor"!
I tried to seek help from xcode output and found this error. I don't know if it's relative